# Get/set value of clicked choice in Select2 multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 as multiselect on an input field. I am trying to find out which choice is being clicked, but if I look at the event thrown when clicking a choice ("choice-selected") all I can find is event.target.value which is the data array with all selected options (choices). Basically I want to access the clicked value so I can let the user edit a custom attribute in that specific choice. How could I go about doing that?

JSFiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JtTTF/

```
$(test).bind("choice-selected", function(e) {
 alert(e.target.value);
    // this is where i would like to access the clicked choice id so i can edit the custom data attribute "reason"
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this as well. After examining the select2.js source code, I found that the *choice-selected* event passes a second parameter: the dom element you clicked.

This dom element contains a data object with key "select2-data".

Your code might look something like this:

```
$(test).on("choice-selected", function(e, choice) {
    var data = $(choice).data('select2-data');
    alert(data.reason ? 'Reason: ' + data.reason : 'No Reason');
});
```

I've updated [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtTTF/3/) accordingly.

Comment: Could you please share what version of Select2 you were using to achieve this? I can't find any mention of the choice-selected event in the current docs: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation

Comment: @Marklar, have you found the answer. Me too coulndn't find choise-selected event. David which version did you use?

Comment: @ErlanI believe I used a combination of `createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {` and `$(dataField).on("select2-selecting", function(e, choice) {`. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe start a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var selected = {};
$(test).change(function () {
    var selections = $(this).select2('data');
    $.each(selections, function (idx, obj) {
        if (!selected[obj.id]) {
            selected[obj.id] = obj;
            $('#selectedText').text(JSON.stringify(obj));
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LfFpx/)

*Note: Haven't seen whether there is inbuilt support to do this, but a custom implementation*